# In react.js App after adding js script to html it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react app I have a code like this

```
<div>{someVariable}</div>
const someVariabe = "<p id="test">Test</p>
<script>setInterval(() => alert('!!!'), 5000)</script>"
```

after rendering my HTML looks like

```
<div>
   <p id="test">Test</p>
   <script>setInterval(() => alert('!!!'), 5000)</script>
</div>
```

But the script doesn't work, why? 
It doesn't need DOM, I tried to reload the page after adding the script but nothing happens.

1. Maybe the system doesn't understand that it is script and there is another way to add it?
2. Maybe the script will be running just in head or body directly?

Comment: @gregoirelodi why did you put a salutation *in*?! If present, they should be removed, you certainly shouldn't be editing them into posts (see e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I suggest the following: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: maybe my description was no clear,  I have some field and user can add there text or HTML or html+script , i don't know it in advance, this content should be inserted into the page and if it has script it should be runnig

Answer (score 0):

You should place your `setInterval` either in a lifecycle method, in case you use classes, or in an effect hook if you're using hooks:

Classes:

```
componentDidMount () {
  setInterval(() => alert('!!!'), 5000)
}
```

Hooks:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => alert('!!!'), 5000)
}, []) // [] to mimic didMount
```

Comment: in my case, it doesn't work, I have some field and user can add there text or HTML or html+script , i don't know it in advance, this content should be inserted into page and if it has script it should be runnig